# Steam: couldn't find bootstrap ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, games, steam

after installing steam through terminal using 'sudo apt-get install steam'

steam downloaded and got stuck on checking for updates and prompted that it was unable to connect event though my internet is working.
I again tried to start steam through command line

```
mask@KUKU:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2017-06-22 13:37:59] Startup - updater built Jun  8 2017 04:33:02
[2017-06-22 13:37:59] Verifying installation...
[2017-06-22 13:37:59] Unable to read and verify install manifest 
/home/mask/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2017-06-22 13:37:59] Verification complete
[2017-06-22 13:37:59] Downloading update...
[2017-06-22 13:37:59] Checking for available updates...
[2017-06-22 13:38:00] Download failed: http error 0 (client-    ]download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12)
[2017-06-22 13:38:00] Download failed: http error 0 (media.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12)
[2017-06-22 13:38:00] failed to load manifest from buffer.
[2017-06-22 13:38:00] Failed to load manifest
[2017-06-22 13:38:00] Error: Download failed: http error 0
[2017-06-22 13:38:00] Error: Steam needs to be online to update. Please confirm your network connection and try again.
[2017-06-22 13:38:02] Shutdown
threadtools.cpp (3294) : Assertion Failed: Illegal termination of worker thread 'Thread(0x0x57d04d60/0x0xf4d8eb'
Error: Couldn't find bootstrap, it's not safe to reset Steam. Please contact technical support.
```

Answer (score 0):

i was with this same issue, try installing libnss-resolve:i386

type on your terminal: **sudo apt install libnss-resolve:i386**

and see the magic happens ;)

At least, it worked for me, good luck.